# Connecting Android app with online database

Tags: android, laravel

While running the app on emulator I give the Http Url(used for json parsing)="http://192.68.43.147/events" where "events" is my route in routes.php(I am working on PHP laravel framework).I want to know what url to give while hosting the website live on a server.

Comment: What you have there is an IP address on your local network.  As far as the device cares, that is the same thing as a web site server.  So you would replace that with whatever your domain is.

Comment: So will it directly access the route or I have to give the path of the file in which route is written? @durbnpoisn

Answer (score 0):

When you make a request to your live Laravel site, you will send the request to `www.yourdomain.com/events`. You do not need to specify the path of the file of the routes.php file, Laravel does that for you. [The docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/lifecycle) have some explanation of the request lifecycle in Laravel if you want to know more. When you configure your .htaccess file (for Apache) or your configuration file for nginx, it will point to the index.php file that Laravel uses for bootstrapping your application, which will eventually wind referring to your routes.php file.